# Building node from source - Library “tls” not found

Tags: node

I get this error message when compiling binaries.

```
Error: Library "tls" not found.
Hint: try: dune external-lib-deps --missing src/bin_node/main.exe src/bin_client/main_client.exe src/bin_client/main_admin.exe src/bin_signer/main_signer.exe src/lib_protocol_compiler/main_native.exe src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/bin_baker/main_baker_003_PsddFKi3.exe src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/bin_endorser/main_endorser_003_PsddFKi3.exe src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/bin_accuser/main_accuser_003_PsddFKi3.exe
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am Running High Sierra 10.13.6, and following instructions from Corey Soreff....mainnet. I ran Make build-does before running make. Now command not found when trying sudo apt-get update

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Tezos! Could you please specify your platform ? the branch you checked out ? which instructions you are following ? did you run `make build-deps` before running `make` ?

Comment: I am Running High Sierra 10.13.6...following instructions from Corey Soreff....mainnet, I ran Make build-does before running make....now command not found when trying sudo apt-get update

Comment: Did you try following the hint ?

Comment: I am a newbie and did not understand how to

Comment: Type the command it says

Comment: Do I need to install XQuartz?

Comment: no idea. I don’t know why you are asking neither.

Comment: I don’t know how to install gimp pkg-config ?

Comment: I tried typing the hint and it asked me to install gmp pkg-config

Comment: Go to telegram t.me/tezosplatform

Comment: I had to install the pkg via brew

Comment: Thanks for your help.... got past that hurdle now generating Tezos-node identity

Comment: ok cool then i posted my original comment as answer. Please accept if that is the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error message is giving you instructions on how to install the missing dependencies. Just follow the hints and install what is requested.

In your case your error message was telling you to try:

`dune external-lib-deps`

and on a Mac with brew can try:

`brew install external-lib-deps`

It is common to have several such missing dependencies that will give these errors and each one will need to be installed.

Comment: @luchonacho edited with the hint that your error message was inviting the user to try

Comment: @luchonacho fyi on TSE if the answer is fully satisfying, it is custom (and important for TSE) that you accept it by clicking on the “checkmark” icon next to the best answer.

Comment: Indeed (being using TSE for 8 years now :) ). Notice I'm not the OP. I did not ask the question.

Comment: @luchonacho aha i did not realize TSE was that old! I thought it came to life 43 days ago ;) yea sorry initially i thought OP was commenting :)

Comment: Oh, I though by TSE you meant "the stack echange [network]", and not Tezos SE. hehe. All confusion around here.